# WPF Canvas Performance Issues

Tags: wpf, performance, canvas

First off let me mention that I have looked through many, many, many, many, many articles and forums on performance in WPF.  I realize this is going to be close to a repost of another article, but please bear with me.

First, I am creating a 2D CAD program in WPF.  Originally my idea was to use Shape objects and use the built-in hit testing/etc.  This was not good enough for performance, as I will need upwards of 5000 lines/arcs showing on the screen.

Here are the different things I've tried:

- Using Shape objects and adding them as children to the Canvas
- Overriding the Canvas' OnRender method and using DrawingContext
- directly Creating a VisualHost and using DrawingVisuals, updated only
  when the DrawingVisual object changes.

In each circumstance, I am left with nearly the same fate:  at around 2000 lines, movement starts to drag behind.  Specifically, I can select a group of lines and tell them to move.  they react to the mouse movement to move (as in most CAD programs).  There is considerable lag to wait for these objects to catch up.

I am at a loss here.  I have read every article I can find and have still not found a solution.  My next option is to go back to GDI+ to accomplish what I need, but I'm looking for a WPF solution if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's all UI updates. Threading is irrelevant.

Comment: Explain more clearly what you are moving once you have 2000 lines on screen and how you are doing it. Also, are you only ever drawing lines? Are we expecting to draw images or polygons?

Comment: I apologize for the late response.  I found an important piece of information out that I didn't know before.  By default, WPF shapes use anti-aliasing.  This was severely limiting my drawing performance.  Second, WPF (even without anti-aliasing) simply wasn't fast enough for the performance I desired.  I have switched to SharpDX.

Comment: There is a lot of tricks to have better performance in WPF, where i worked, we have a wpf application with 12k pixels by 11k pixels, where we can zoom in/zoom out, and pan, with something like 2k cotnrols (each control is like a button, a screw, a switch, etc...) and we finally succeeded to have acceptable performance after a few months, if you want more information just tell me

Comment: @oppassum - mark you post as answered if you have solved your problem (you can answer yourself if need be).

Comment: @mlemay I am stuck with a similar problem having a Canvas with an image and +30k points and other shapes. What was your solution ?